# How to Populate a Drop down box from a mySQL table in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a mysql database with a drivers table which has the following fields:
id
forename
surname
nationality
team_id

I am trying to create a PHP which retrieves the names and id of each driver and then the output should contain an HTML form which should contain a submit button and a Drop-down box. The drop-down input should contain the driver names, and the form should submit via the GET method to another php named task4.php when the submit button is pressed.

I have started doing some of the code but unable to finish it.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("hostname","login","password","db_name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT forename, surname, id FROM Drivers);

$options="";

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$id=$row["forename"];
$thing=$row["surname"];
$options.="OPTION VALUE=\"$id\">".$forename;
}
?>
```

Please Help Me

Comment: A couple of things - the first is a missing quote at the end of your call to `mysqli_query`. You're also trying to use mysql_fetch_array - you can't mix calls to mysqli_ and mysql_ functions.

Comment: Furthermore you do not have to store the values from `$row` into new variables, if you directly use it. And you are missing the opening "<" and the closing "</option>". -> `$options .= "<option value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row["forename"] . "</option>";`.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a result from the `SELECT` statement, it comes in the form `$row['columnName']`.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT forename, surname, id FROM Drivers");

$options="<select>";

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $options .= '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["forename"].' '.$row["surname"].'</option>';

}

$options .= '</select>';

echo '<form action="task4.php">';
echo $options;
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit">';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: You're using `mysql_fetch_array`, on a result set from `mysqli_query`. That isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("hostname","login","password","db_name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$query = 'SELECT id, forename, surname FROM Drivers';

if($result = mysqli_query($con, $query))
{

    $options="";

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $id=$row['id'];
        $surname=$row['surname'];
        $forename = $row['forename'];
        $options.="<option value='$id'>" . $forename . ' ' . $surname . '</option>';
    }
    echo '<form name="form1" action="task4.php" method="get">';
        echo '<select name="dropdown">';
            echo $options;
        echo '</select>'</br>;
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Send">';
    echo '</form>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, how about if I wanted to make it so that when the user selects a specific driver by name, it is their id rather than their name that is submitted to task4.php

Comment: The value in the option tag is also the value being passed along. If you wanted it to be the forename use the forename for the value attribute. In my example I pass along $id in the value. So whatever value id is returned from the database it will use that. The text in between `<option>` and `</option>` is the text you see on screen. This won't affect the value being passed through the GET method.

Comment: So currently this code is passing along the id, so how about if i wanted to pass along the forename and the surname

Comment: You could use `$forename.$surname` to pass it along instead of `$id`.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you start.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("hostname","login","password","db_name");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
}    

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT forename, surname, id FROM Drivers);
?>

<form action='form4.php' method='get'>
<select name='driver_name'>

<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='{$row['id']}'>".$row['forename']." ".$row['lastname']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```